# Why cargo-install needs `--locked` to work?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I tried to install cargo-sort by force

```
cargo install --force cargo-sort
```

However, it complains

```
error: failed to compile `cargo-sort v1.0.9`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/var/folders/2q/sfkj3vg13z175flb8j9znf9w0000gn/T/cargo-installJcyWnG`

Caused by:
  package `clap_builder v4.4.0` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.70.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.67.0-nightly
  Try re-running cargo install with `--locked
```

My rust toolchain is

```
nightly-2022-11-15-x86_64-apple-darwin (override)
```

Since it suggested me to use `--locked`. So I use

```
cargo install --force --locked cargo-sort
```

It worked.

My Cargo.lock is https://github.com/pingcap/tidb-engine-ext/blob/raftstore-proxy/Cargo.lock.

From rust's doc, I know `--locked` means using the version required in Cargo.lock. However, I find there is no entry about `clap_builder` in my Cargo.lock.

My question is why `--locked` can work? I don't think Cargo.lock has contributed anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> From rust's doc, I know `--locked` means using the version required in `Cargo.lock`. However, I find there is no entry about clap_builder in my `Cargo.lock`.

In the case of `cargo install`, the lock file used is the one in *the package you're installing* (`cargo-sort`). `cargo install` doesn't interact with the package in the current directory at all, unless you ask it to install that package.

You can use docs.rs to view [the lock file for `cargo-sort` version `1.0.9`](https://docs.rs/crate/cargo-sort/1.0.9/source/Cargo.lock) It doesn't have an entry for `clap_builder` either, but that's because the older version of `clap` in that file doesn't use `clap_builder` at all.

---

All that said, you should probably update your Rust toolchains, and use `stable` instead of `nightly`; then you won't need `--locked` because you'll be able to build the latest `clap` and other packages. It's not wise to build *anything* with a nightly compiler unless it is required — nightlies may have serious bugs.

If you want to continue using nightly for development, you can install with stable by asking for it:

```bash
cargo +stable install cargo-sort
```

Comment: So the reason why `cargo install --force --locked cargo-sort` can work is that the clap in Cargo.lock is old, it doesn't depend on clap_builder. However, you suggest I install cargo-sort with `+stable` even if I develop with nightly which is not a good practice?

Comment: While nightly has more potential for issues, I can't recall having any. I believe the actual reason why stable works and nightly didn't is because your version of stable is newer than nightly. Run `rustup update` and try again?